# why combobox select first item when reload windows

Tags: visual-studio-2010, select, combobox

i creat a windows form and used a combobox with databinding. 
when i save the windows and reload windows to edit items , every time combobox select first item but is saved other item .
please help me.
thanks

Comment: i used visual studio databinding option ; right click in the combobox and use databound item i uploded the picture in this address :

http://doondle.net/1.png

Comment: You should set `Combo.SelectedValue = item.groupID` on window reload

Comment: this is ok . combo.selectedvalue = item.groupid is set.    all items save in person table . but i a have a item "GroupID" that linked to groups table    this picture : http://doondle.net/2.png

Answer (score 0):

i used visual studio databinding option ; 
right click in the combobox and use databound item
i uploded the picture in this address :

http://doondle.net/1.png